# XMLファイルの上書き

Tags: php, xml

```xml
<Alert>
   name=‘mmm’ 
    hope=‘kk’
    <test>
       Name=’kkm’ 
     </test>
</Alert>
```

```php
$str = “test”;
$fileName = “test-fileName”;
$xml = simplexml_load_file( sampleXml);
(String)$xml->Alert->attribute()->hope = $str;
$xml->saveXML($fileName);
```

要素取得はできるんですが、書き換えができないようで。。。
何かいい方法、知らないでしょうか？

パーミッションの権限は書き込みも読み込みもできています。

Answer (score 1):

XMLが体裁をなしていないですが、このフォーマットのままhopeの値を書き換えたければ、Alertのテキストを取得して、文字列置換をするなり、キーバリューのフォーマットとして別途パースするなりの必要があります。

もし、もう少しXMLらしく書き直してよいのであれば、一例として、以下のコードでhopeの書き換えは可能です。

```
<?php
    $str = 'test';
    $fileName = './new.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('./sample.xml');
    (String)$xml->alert->attributes()->hope = $str;
    $xml->saveXML($fileName);
?>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <alert hope="kk">
  </alert>
</root>
```